# Regex to append extension to file path

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to get running a GitHub action link checker that checks markdown files for URLs. I have a Jekyll site.

The link checker looks for files, rather than full URLs, as a result:

This fails - `/docs/article1/`

But this works - `/docs/article1.md`

I have the following rewrite in place that works for most use cases:

```
{
  "pattern": "(\\S+)\/(\\s|$)",
  "replacement": "$1$2"
}
```

However, it does not work if the trailing slash is missing from the the link.

Can someone recommend a regex update that will capture either:

- `/docs/article1/`
- `/docs/article1`

And rewrite it as `/docs/article1.md`?

Comment: `(\\S+)\/?(\\s|$)` probably will help. "?" tells - match 1 or 0 occurrences of previous element. For replacement `$1$2\.md` should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string you're checking will be always

`/<name>/<name>[/]`

then
`(\S+?)\/(\S+?)\/?$`
with substitution
`$1/$2.md`
should work. ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/6QeKoU/1))

Regex explanation

```
(     // group 1
\\S+?    // any character, more than 1, lazy (until there is '/')
)     // close group 1
\/    // the '/' between the names
(     // group 2
\\S+?    // any character, more than 1, lazy (until there is '/' or $(end of line))
)     // close group 2
\/?   // ignore if there is closing '/'
$     // the end of line
```

(Here is a snippet showing that it works)

```js
let reg = {
  "pattern": "(\\S+?)\/(\\S+?)\/?$",
  "replacement": "$1/$2.md"
};

let tests = ["/a/b","/a/b/","/document/data/", "/document/data", "/docs/article1/", "/docs/article1"];

// run RegExp replace on every one from tests
tests.forEach(e => {
  let replaced =
  e.replace(new RegExp(reg.pattern), reg.replacement)
   console.log(e, "=>", replaced)
})
```

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions):

> Appending the `?` character to a quantifier makes it lazy; it causes the regular expression engine to match as few occurrences as possible

And from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers):

> By default quantifiers like `*` and `+` are "greedy", meaning that they try to match as much of the string as possible. The `?` character after the quantifier makes the quantifier "non-greedy": meaning that it will stop as soon as it finds a match.